# Vectorized dataframe filtering with complex logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I have a very big dataframe with five columns, ID and four numerical. Let's say, integers between 0 and 50. My goal is to calculate cosine similarity matrix for every ID.

However, I want to force some of that matrix values to `np.nan`. Namely, if within the given ID a row (lets say 1) is not worse than the other row (lets say 2) in all four dimensions while being better in at least one, then the similarity matrix at coordinates [1, 2] and [2, 1] must be set to `np.nan`.

Sample dataframe:

```
a   b   c   d   ID
9   9   7   3   1
9   8   3   2   1
6   5   5   6   1
8   4   7   5   1
4   8   7   2   1
4   6   9   5   1
7   4   3   1   1
5   3   5   2   1
8   9   3   9   1
8   2   7   9   1
6   4   1   1   2
3   9   9   3   2
7   6   7   7   2
7   4   9   3   2
2   5   9   2   2
7   6   2   3   2
5   8   7   5   2
6   9   4   1   3
1   6   8   6   3
1   9   7   6   3
2   8   5   4   3
7   2   5   1   3
9   6   5   3   3
8   2   3   2   3
1   8   2   9   3
1   8   1   6   3
3   6   2   4   3
4   2   9   7   3
9   2   6   8   3
1   2   6   3   3
```

I came up with a function which outputs indices of rows which happen to follow the rule above:

```py
def filter_se(row, df, cols = None):
    if cols:
        df = df[cols]
        row = row[cols]
    #filter for all rows where none of the columns are worse
    df = df[(row >= df).all(axis = 1)]
    #filter for rows where any column is better.
    df = df[(row > df).any(axis = 1)]
    indexes = df.index.tolist()
    return indexes

sample_group = sample.groupby("ID")
r = {}
for index, group in sample_group:
    res = group.apply(filter_se, args = [group, ["a", "b", "c", "d"]], axis = 1).tolist()
    
    r[index] = res

Output: r
{1: [[1, 4, 6, 7], [6], [7], [6, 7], [], [], [], [], [6], []],
 2: [[], [14], [10, 15], [10], [], [10], []],
 3: [[],
  [29],
  [25, 29],
  [],
  [],
  [21, 23],
  [],
  [25],
  [],
  [],
  [29],
  [21, 23, 29],
  []]}
```

Similarity matrix for each ID I calculated this way:

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

sims = sample.groupby("ID").apply(lambda g: cosine_similarity(g[["a", "b", "c", "d"]]))
```

This gives me a `pd.Series` object with similarity matrix being values and IDs being index. The next step is to set the elements of that matrix to `np.nan` which I am struggling with.
I would like to ask for help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for a group with a given ID. In the general setting, it can be applied to each ID group. `df` is the dataframe with the data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# select the group with a specified ID and convert it into a numpy array
ID = 1
arr = df[df["ID"] == ID][["a", "b", "c", "d"]].to_numpy()

# compute the similarity matrix for this group
b = arr[..., None]
c = arr.T[None, ...]
mask = (((b >= c).all(axis=1)) & ((b > c).any(axis=1)))
mask |= mask.T
sims = np.where(mask, np.nan, cosine_similarity(arr))
```

Comment: thank you. could you explain a bit the logic behind the mask?

Comment: @EmilMirzayev It uses `all` and `any` the same way as in your code. Broadcasting is used to make the comparisons for all pairs of rows in a vectorized manner instead of iterating over rows. `mask |= mask.T` symmetrizes `mask`, so that if `mask[i,j]` is `True`, then `mask[j,i]` will have the same value.

Comment: thank you for explanation! This is indeed seems to be exactly what I needed. I am not very used to bitwise operations, but this is great way to do things